# Lifting of curves with respect to a Lie group action

Tags: lie-groups, complex-geometry

Let $G$ be a complex Lie group. Let $M$ a complex $G$-manifold.  Given any point $x\in M$, the orbit $G\cdot x$ is a complex submanifod of $M$.

My question is the following: given an analytic curve $\gamma: \mathbb{C} \to G\cdot x$ with $\gamma(0)=x$, does there exists an analytic curve $\tilde{\gamma}: \mathbb{C} \to G$ such that $\tilde{\gamma}(0)=e_G$ and $\tilde{\gamma}(t)\cdot x = \gamma(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{C}$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is a nice question and I am not sure that I am able to give complete answer. However, here is a strategy to look for counterexample:

Assume that $X = G/H$, where $H$ is a closed complex subgroup. Then $X$ is naturally endowed with holomorphic principal $H$ bundle with total space isomorphic to $G$. 

If the answer to your question is positive, this would imply that after restriction to any analytical curve  this bundle admits a holomorphic section. I think you might  construct a counterexample, although a couple of constructions which came to my mind firstly don't really work.

Comment: @Rogov   We are always able to construct a local lifting of $\gamma$. Am I right?

Comment: @V.Rogov: Every holomorphic fiber bundle over an open Riemann surface is holomorphically trivial (this is Grauert-Rohrl's theorem). https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb78/1ab26e6da62985d22e8b3ca34a33eeb0c299.pdf

Comment: @MoisheCohen wow, I have had such a suspection before but never heard about this theorem! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is positive, you can even replace the complex line with an arbitrary open Riemann surface $S$ (the most natural one besides ${\mathbb C}$ would be ${\mathbb C}^*$). Here is a proof. Let $H< G$ denote the stabilizer of $x\in M$; it is a complex Lie subgroup of $G$. Then $G/H$ is equivariantly biholomorphic to the submanifold $Gx\subset M$. Thus, the problem reduces to the lifting problem for holomorphic maps $f: S\to B=G/H$. The projection $\xi: G\to B$ is a  principal holomorphic $H$-bundle. Let $\eta=f^*\xi$ be its pull-back to $S$: The bundle $\eta: E\to S$ is again a holomorphic bundle (with the fiber $H$) over $S$. Recall that $E$ can be identified with the submanifold
$$
\{(x,y)\in S\times G: f(x)= \xi(y)\}
$$

By a theorem due to Grauert and Rohrl (see [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/bb78/1ab26e6da62985d22e8b3ca34a33eeb0c299.pdf)), every holomorphic bundle over an open Riemann surface is holomorphically trivial. (Famously, this theorem fails if the base is a Stein manifold of dimension $\ge 2$.) Let $\sigma: S\to E$ be a holomorphic section of $\eta$. Then composing $\sigma$ with the projection 
$E\to G$ we obtain the required holomorphic lift $\tilde{f}: S\to G$ of the mapping $f: S\to B$.

Comment: @ Moishe Cohen:Thanks a lot.